# Translation from C# to Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, code-translation

I need help translating part of the C# code to Delphi.
I would very much appreciate any help or advice.

```
unsafe {
    fixed (byte* bpt = &buff[140]) {
        byte b1 = bpt[0];
        byte b2 = bpt[1];
        byte b3 = bpt[2];
        byte b4 = bpt[3];
    }
}
```

I tried several ways, defining a record with 4 byte vars, defining tbytearray, but nothing seems to be right.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks.

UPDATE

Since it seems that I haven't defined my questions right, since this is my first question, here is the complete function on C#.

```
        private void ProcessCommAlarm_V40(ref CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_ALARMER pAlarmer, IntPtr pAlarmInfo, uint dwBufLen, IntPtr pUser)
        {
            MyDebugInfo AlarmInfo = new MyDebugInfo(DebugInfo);

            byte[] buff = new byte[dwBufLen];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pAlarmInfo, buff, 0, (int)dwBufLen);           

            string sBuff = "";

            if (dwBufLen - 140 > 0 && (dwBufLen - 140) % 4 == 0)
            {
                int msgType = BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 0);
                string sMsgType = "";
                bool bAcceptedMsg = false;
                int nTargetType = 0; 

                switch (msgType)
                {
                    case 2:
                        sMsgType = "Video Loss"; bAcceptedMsg = true; nTargetType = 1; break;

                    case 3:
                        sMsgType = "Motion"; nTargetType = 1; break;
                }                

                if (bAcceptedMsg)
                {
                    int nTotalElements = BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 12);

                    if ((nTargetType == 1 && nTotalElements <= CHCNetSDK.MAX_CHANNUM_V30) || (nTargetType == 2 && nTotalElements <= CHCNetSDK.MAX_DISKNUM_V30))
                    {
                        
                        int len = nTotalElements * 4;
                        byte[] channels = new byte[len];

                        unsafe
                        {
                            fixed (byte* bpt = &buff[140])
                            {
                                byte b1 = bpt[0];
                                byte b2 = bpt[1];
                                byte b3 = bpt[2];
                                byte b4 = bpt[3];

                                IntPtr dwDataAddress = new IntPtr(b1 + b2 * (1 << 8) + b3 * (1 << 16) + b4 * (1 << 24));
                                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(dwDataAddress, channels, 0, len);
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i <= len - 4; i += 4)
                        {                            
                            sBuff += string.Format("Channel No: {0}", BitConverter.ToInt32(channels, i));
                            sBuff += Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, this is what I have done so far, which includes the change given my @remy-lebeau.

```
procedure ProcessCommAlarm_V40(pAlarmer: LPNET_DVR_ALARMER; pAlarmInfo: PChar; dwBufLen: DWORD; dwUser: DWORD);
var
  buff: array of byte;
  msgType: Integer;
  sMsgType: String;
  bAcceptedMsg: Boolean;
  nTargetType: Integer;
  sBuff: String;
  nTotalElements: Integer;
  channels: array of byte;
  len: Integer;
  b1,b2,b3,b4:byte;
  bpt: pbyte;
  dwDataAddress: IntPtr;
  I: Integer;
begin
  sBuff := '';

  SetLength(buff, dwBufLen);
  CopyMemory(buff, pAlarmInfo, dwBufLen);

  if (dwBufLen - 140 > 0) and ((dwBufLen - 140) mod 4 = 0) then begin
    msgType := Integer(buff[0]);
    sMsgType := '';
    bAcceptedMsg := false;
    nTargetType := 0;

    case (msgType) of
      2:
        begin
          sMsgType := 'Video loss';
          bAcceptedMsg := true;
          nTargetType := 1;
        end;
    end;

    if (bAcceptedMsg) then
    begin
      nTotalElements := buff[12];
      if ((nTargetType = 1) and (nTotalElements <= MAX_CHANNUM_V30)) or ((nTargetType = 2) and (nTotalElements <= MAX_DISKNUM_V30)) then begin
        len := nTotalElements * 4;
        SetLength(channels,len);

        bpt := @buff[140];
        b1 := bpt[0];
        b2 := bpt[1];
        b3 := bpt[2];
        b4 := bpt[3];

        dwDataAddress := IntPtr(b1 + b2 * (1 shl 8) + b3 * (1 shl 16) + b4 * (1 shl 24));

        sBuff := sBuff + IntToStr(dwDataAddress);
        sBuff := sBuff + #10 + #13;

        CopyMemory(Channels, @dwDataAddress, len);

        I:=0;
        while (i <= len - 4) do begin
          sBuff := sBuff + 'Channel No: ' + IntToStr(channels[i]);
          sBuff := sBuff + #13 + #10;
          i:= i + 4;
        end;
      end;
    end
  end;
end;
```

Can someone please recheck the translation, because Delphi code is not reproducing the same results as C#.

UPDATE:

After reading the detailed explanation @Remy wrote down below, I was able to reproduce the same results on both applications in C# and in Delphi.

The code which now is working is below.

```
procedure ProcessCommAlarm_V40(pAlarmer: LPNET_DVR_ALARMER; pAlarmInfo: IntPtr; dwBufLen: DWORD; dwUser: IntPtr);
var
  buff: array of byte;
  channels: array of byte;
  msgType: Integer;
  sMsgType: String;
  bAcceptedMsg: Boolean;
  nTargetType: Integer;
  sBuff: String;
  nTotalElements: Integer;
  len: Integer;
  b1,b2,b3,b4:byte;
  bpt: pbyte;
  dwDataAddress: IntPtr;
  I: Integer;
  x:pbyte;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('H:m:s',now));
  sBuff := '';

  SetLength(buff, dwBufLen);
  CopyMemory(buff, Pointer(pAlarmInfo), dwBufLen);

  if (dwBufLen - 140 > 0) and ((dwBufLen - 140) mod 4 = 0) then begin
    msgType := Integer(buff[0]);
    sMsgType := '';
    bAcceptedMsg := false;
    nTargetType := 0;

    case (msgType) of
      2:
        begin
          sMsgType := 'Video loss';
          bAcceptedMsg := true;
          nTargetType := 1;
        end;
    end;

    if (bAcceptedMsg) then
    begin
      nTotalElements := buff[12];
      if ((nTargetType = 1) and (nTotalElements <= MAX_CHANNUM_V30)) or ((nTargetType = 2) and (nTotalElements <= MAX_DISKNUM_V30)) then begin
        len := nTotalElements * 4;
        SetLength(channels,len);

        bpt := @buff[140];
        b1 := bpt[0];
        b2 := bpt[1];
        b3 := bpt[2];
        b4 := bpt[3];

        dwDataAddress := IntPtr(b1 + b2 * (1 shl 8) + b3 * (1 shl 16) + b4 * (1 shl 24));
        CopyMemory(Channels, Pointer(dwDataAddress), len);

        I:=0;
        while (i <= len - 4) do begin
          sBuff := sBuff + 'Channel No: ' + IntToStr(channels[i]);
          sBuff := sBuff + #13 + #10;
          i:= i + 4;
        end;
      end;
    end
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You should show what you have done and tell how you verify it is correct or not.

Comment: @fpiette, thanks for your comment, I apologize, this is my first post. I have updated the question.

Comment: This isn't a translation service.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am aware of that, but I am stuck on this part of the code for 10 days now in project with over 20000 lines. So, I know it's not by the rules, I know I'm asking to much, but I really need help from someone who is more experienced than me in this field.

Comment: @Mark Have you tried debugging the code to see where its behavior deviates from your expectations?  This is a Q&A site, not a debugging service.  You should focus on *specific questions*.

Comment: Exactly. If you've got 20k lines of code, it's time to learn how to debug. You should find a different site if you want this kind of service. Our rules exist for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `buff: array[0..MaxLimit] of Byte;` where MaxLimit is >= 143;

In Delphi 2009 and later:

```pascal
var
  bpt: PByte;
  b1, b2, b3, b4: Byte;
begin
  bpt := @buff[140];
  b1 := bpt[0];
  b2 := bpt[1];
  b3 := bpt[2];
  b4 := bpt[3];
end;
```

In Delphi 2007 and earlier:

```pascal
var
  bpt: PChar;
  b1, b2, b3, b4: Byte;
begin
  bpt := PChar(@buff[140]);
  b1 := Byte(bpt[0]);
  b2 := Byte(bpt[1]);
  b3 := Byte(bpt[2]);
  b4 := Byte(bpt[3]);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
var
  bpt: PByte;
  b1, b2, b3, b4: Byte;
begin
  bpt := @buff[140];
  b1 := bpt^; Inc(bpt);
  b2 := bpt^; Inc(bpt);
  b3 := bpt^; Inc(bpt);
  b4 := bpt^; Inc(bpt);
end;
```

---

**UPDATE**: That being said, I see a number of problems with your translation.

- in the C# code, the `dwUser` parameter is declared as `IntPtr`, which is a pointer-sized integer.  Delphi also has `IntPtr`.  But in your Delphi code, you have declared the parameter as a `DWORD` instead.  That will work in a 32-bit build, but not in a 64-bit build.  If the parameter ever receives a value more than 32-bits, like a memory address, it will get truncated.  Use `DWORD_PTR` instead, if not `IntPtr`.
- in the C# code, the `pAlarmInfo` parameter is declared as `IntPtr`.  But in your Delphi code, you have declared the parameter as a `PChar` instead.  Though that *can* work, an untyped `Pointer` would have been more appropriate, if not `IntPtr`.
- in Delphi, using `array of bytes` is OK for the `buff` and `channels` variables, though `TBytes` or `TArray<Byte>` would be more preferred in modern Delphi versions.
- using the Win32 `CopyMemory()` function is fine, but you should consider using Delphi's `System.Move()` instead.  In any case, your 1st call to `CopyMemory()` is correct (though, if `pAlarmInfo` is declared as `IntPtr`, you will have to type-cast it to `Pointer`).  However, your 2nd call is wrong.  The C# code is copying `len` bytes from the memory address held in `dwDataAddress`, whereas you are copying `len` bytes from the address of `dwDataAddress` itself.  You need to type-cast `dwDataAddress` to a pointer and copy from the pointed-to address instead.
- your translation of the assignments of `msgType` and `nTotalElements` are wrong. The C# code is extracting a *4-byte integer* from `buff` at indexes `0..3` and `12..15`, respectively.  Your Delphi code is reading *1 byte* at indexes `12` and `15` and scaling their values up to an `Integer`.  Not the same thing.
- you completely omitted case `3` from the `case msgType of` statement.  Probably because it was not setting `bAcceptedMsg = true`.  I suspect that missing assignment might be a bug in the C# code.
- `#10 + #13` should be `#13 + #10`, or simply `#13#10`.  Or, you should use Delphi's `System.sLineBreak` constant instead.
- your translation of reading the `channel` numbers is wrong. Like further above, the C# code is extracting a *4-byte integer* from `channels` at index `i..i+3`, respectively.  Your Delphi code is reading *1 byte* at index `i` and scaling its value up to an `Integer`.

Comment: thank you very much for you answer. I know I'm asking for much, but if you could recheck what I have done so far, that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @Remy, I'm speechless. I really can't thank you enough. I struggled so long with this and you fixed it like it was a breeze. I changed the types of the dwUser to IntPtr, pAlarmData to IntPtr, I changed both CopyMemory functions to cast Pointer as 1) CopyMemory(buff, Pointer(pAlarmInfo), dwBufLen); and 2) CopyMemory(Channels, Pointer(dwDataAddress), len); After this change both C# and Delphi app are reproducing the same output.